# Google Cloud Messaging: Unable to register to subscribe to certain topics - exception=java.io.IOException: INVALID_PARAMETERS

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, ioexception

I've got a weird situation. I've got 3 devices that i registered at GCM.
Two 4.x devices and one 6.0.1.

I'm trying to subscribe my devices to two topic "channels" - "global" & "defaultchannel" - via the subscribeTopics() method in the same way as it's done in google's example app: [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/RegistrationIntentService.java#L99-L104)

My 4.x devices have no issue registering to both topics but my 6.0 device is simple not able to register anywhere else besides the "global" channel.

When the device tries to register at "global" everything goes well, but then when it tries to register at the other channel it always keeps throwing an IOException:

> Failed to complete token refresh: exception=java.io.IOException: INVALID_PARAMETERS

Next to this exception also show me this message on the 6.0 device which is not logged on the other (working) devices:

> W/InstanceID/Rpc: Found 10008

This makes no sense at all to me. Does anyone know how to handle this issue?

Comment: I suggest that you call the application context and not `this` in the instances. That way you can make sure that all your instances are in the same context. It occurs maybe because the `InstanceID.getInstance(this)` and the `GcmPubSub.getInstance(this)` is in different context.

Comment: I've been looking into it again, but now registration to different topics works just fine on all devices whether I use this or getApplicationContext.... strange...